# perl ssh then read file on remote server

Tags: perl, ssh

I need to

1. connect to a remote server; then
2. do some things, like open and read the contents of a file.

For step 1:

```
my $server = "remoteservername.company.com";
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("$server", debug => 1, protocol => 2, StrictHostKeyChecking => "no") or die "Error connecting server $server";
```

yields msg on terminal

> `Connection established.`

so I presume I am ssh connected to remote server, via the code.

For step 2, how do i open and read a file on the remote server using code from the local server? this is the best i can do so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use warnings::register;
use Net::SSH::Perl;
use Net::SSH::Expect;
use Math::BigInt lib => "Calc,GMP,Pari";

my $server = "server09";
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("$server", debug => 1, protocol => 2, StrictHostKeyChecking => "no") or die "Error connecting server $server";

#open(FILE, "/home/myid/f09.txt") || print("Unable to open test.o\n"); #works, on local, opens file[does not fail].

#open(FILE, "server09://home/myid/f09.txt") || print("Unable to open test.o\n");  #---> error: "Unable to open test.o"

my @remote_text = `this text is put into array.`;
my $remote_text = join ('',@remote_text);
open (FILE,'>/home/myid/f09.txt');
print FILE "$remote_text";
close (FILE);

exit(0);
```

yet, it does not add anything to existing file `f09.txt`; also if i delete the file, the `open` does not create it. no errors, but this does not seem to contact the remote file.

just a simple explanation of ssh, then read from remote file would be helpful. other examples i see aren't cutting it. of course, could be me, long day, gotta walk away from it for a while. your time is very much appreciated!

Comment: If I were you, I'd write the Perl script to do everything locally and execute it over ssh.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially trying to modify a file that exists on another machine over SSH.
File operations functions cannot handle that.

Is it possible for you to download the file from the other server, update on your local and re-upload the file?

You may also want to experiment with the ssh command:

```
my @remote_text = ('this text is put into array.');
my $remote_text = join ('',@remote_text);

my @args = ("ssh server09", "echo '$remote_text' > /home/myid/f09.txt");
system(@args) == 0 or die "system @args failed: $?"
```

Comment: you know, i saw another comment to that effect but think, "why the heck not?"/but if it's so, then it is what it is. the ultimate goal is to read a log file, do a "kill -0" on it, if T[rue] then a certain service is running, if not then the service has stopped and needs to be restarted. SO, ?download the file locally, do a "cat" on it to get the pid, do a kill -0 on it, etc...? well, if that gets the job done then i will venture there. *!thx!* for your answer! [the first ! in *!thx!* is not a not, but rather a bang] a little code humor there ;)

Comment: gm - by the way, i only want to read the file, maybe do a read only operation on it. *surely* [!] we can connect to a remote server, then open and read a file?? just wanted to reemphasize that in case it's subtle enough to overlook. please do reply if you have more thoughts. much appreciated!

Comment: this code got me to the next step: [4 spaces not making code block]:
[CODE]
        use strict;
 use warnings;
 use diagnostics;
 use warnings::register;

 use Net::SSH::Perl;
 use Net::SSH::Expect;
 use Math::BigInt lib => "Calc,GMP,Pari";

 my $remote_filename = '/var/log/systemlog';
 my $remote_host = "server.team.domain.com";
 my $cmd = "ssh $remote_host tail -f $remote_filename |";
  open my $remote_tail, $cmd or die "a horrible death!";

  while (<$remote_tail>){
   print "Remote: $_";
  }

 exit(0);
[/CODE]

Answer (score 0):

For performing interesting things over an SSH connection to another machine, you might like to try [`IPC::PerlSSH`](http://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::PerlSSH). From one of its examples:

```
use IPC::PerlSSH;

my $ips = IPC::PerlSSH->new( Host => "over.there" );

$ips->use_library( "FS", qw( mkdir chmod writefile ) );

$ips->call( "mkdir", "/tmp/testing" );
$ips->call( "chmod", 0600, "/tmp/testing" );

$ips->call( "writefile", "/tmp/testing/secret", <<EOF );
Some secret contents of my file here
EOF
```